# Questions about a topological category

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, uniform-spaces

Given topological spaces $(X_i,\tau_i)$ with sets 
$\mathbf S_i=\{\mathcal A\in \tau_i^2|\mathcal A\supseteq\Delta X_i^2\}$, where $\tau^2$ is the product topology and $\Delta$ is the diagonal. The sets **S** make it possible to judge how close to points $x,y\in X$ are to each other: the smaller open sets $\mathcal A\in \mathbf S$ such that $(x,y)\in\mathcal A$, the nearer $(x,y)$ is to the diagonal and the nearer $x$ and $y$ are.

Define function $f:X_1\to X_2$ to be *uniform* iff:

$\;\forall x,y\in \!X_1\, \forall \mathcal E_2\!\in \mathbf S_2\, \exists\mathcal D_1\in\mathbf
S_1: ((x,y)\in\mathcal D_1\implies(f(x), f(y))\in\mathcal E_2)$
$\qquad$ or equivalent
$\;\mathcal E_2\!\in \mathbf S_2\implies((f\times f)^{-1}(\mathcal E_2)\subseteq \mathbf S_1 $.

Apparently, topological spaces $X$ with "uniform" functions form a category since the identity and the composition of "uniform" functions are "uniform" functions, and it would be interesting to know things about that category, for example *if the inverse of a bijective morphism is a morphism*.

> It should be pointed out perhaps, that this category is not the
>   category of uniform spaces and as far as I know the morphisms in
>   general don't have to be continuous.

Further I wonder if "uniformity" is equivalent with

$\mathcal B\subseteq X_2\times X_2\implies((x,y)\in\overline{(f\times f)^{-1}(\mathcal B)}\implies (f(x),f(y))\in\overline{\mathcal B})$?

See also: [Is this a criterion for continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072334/is-this-a-criterion-for-continuity) about a similar but not equal condition on a function.

Comment: Forget i and j and take $(x,y)\in A$ for a $A\in S$. As $S\subseteq \Delta$, $(x,y)\in\Delta$, which implies $x = y$... And then basically your $f$ is uniform (in your sense) if and only if $x = y$ implies $f(x) = f(y)$ because you can always take $D = \Delta X_i$ whatever $E$ you might take...

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion but I have corrected the error.

Comment: Btw, how the hell did you came up with such a definition ? You don't even ask that $S_j$ contains $(f(x),f(y))$ and $D_i$ contains $(x,y)$ ! This, plus the fact that definition changes in an other post... Really...

Answer (score 1):

The fonction $x \mapsto 1/x$ defined on $[1,+\infty[$ is uniformly continuous. (Exercise !) The function $x\mapsto 1/x$ defined on $]0,1]$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous (exercise again !) and these two functions are inverse one to each other.

As on a metric space, with the uniform structure given by the metric, being uniform amouts to be uniformly continuous, the previous toy example shows that the inverse of a bijective morphism is not necessarily a morphism in the category of uniform spaces with uniform maps as morphisms.

For you other question, the answer is yes, and I also think that it is a proposition in Bourbaki, Topologie générale, Chapitre II, or maybe an exercise in the exercises for this chapter, but I don't have it next to me, so that I cannot confirm.

**EDIT** : after the edit of the question, what is meant is not leading to a uniform structure indeed, and is definitely not a uniform structure as well.

The *also* from your *see also* is misplaced, as the definitions of uniformity are not the same here and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072334/is-this-a-criterion-for-continuity). This question has horribly bad natations (i,j etc) and is too much unprecise and changing.

Comment: Yes I am ! I don't like to point towards wikipedia, but you could have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space. Validate if you are satisfied.

Comment: I know that your definition is not the one of entourages and uniformity from the uniform spaces framework. Nevertheless, what you mean to define is a uniform structure, even if you did a mistake in your definition. Forget i and j and take $(x,y)\in A$ for a $A\in S$. As $S\subseteq \Delta$, $(x,y)\in\Delta$, which implies $x = y$, and everything written after this is trivial. That is your mistake. Now, if you try to mean by $x$ is near $y$ something like $(x,y)$ is near the diagonal, whatever yo do, you'll be *obliged* to define a... uniform structure !

Comment: Okay, thank you! I have corrected my error, but have not defined a uniform space.

Comment: Ok, thx for having edited your question. I will now edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the material that you later erased! You might be right about some of your criticism, but I must say you have a bad temper.